# How to strike out text in excel cell using interop?

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop

In my application client requires to strikeout certain parts of text in a cell, and certain parts should not be strike out.

Is there any way to do this in C# com Interop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range.Characters` gives access to individual characters in a cell, including their formatting (`Font` property).

See [in excel VBA, how to retrieve the formats of text within a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461556/in-excel-vba-how-to-retrieve-the-formats-of-text-within-a-cell).